# GPG error Installing RabbitMQ via Cloudsmith On Ubuntu

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg, rabbitmq

I've tried following the instructions provided by RabbitMQ to install, as they said what's available with Ubuntu isn't the latest, and I can use the latest repos they provide.

However, the instructions for Cloudsmith get stuck when trying to apt-get after adding all of the repository sources/gpg keys.

For reference, it is these instructions: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-cloudsmith

After adding the sources/gpg keys, it asks to run `sudo apt-get update -y` again.  This presents the following error:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu/ focal: /usr/share/keyrings/rabbitmq-rabbitmq-server-archive-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/io.cloudsmith.rabbitmq.9F4587F226208342.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am really not sure what to do about this, as I've just been following the Cloudsmith IO instructions top to bottom up until getting stuck at this point.

I saw that others have had similar issues with different software, and the solution was to just delete the PGP keys, and the sources file.   That doesn't seem like a proper fix, as it's just literally skipping everything.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, for reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really NEED the latest from upstream? The version in the Ubuntu repositories is slightly older, but works well, is compatible with newer versions, is secure, and is easy to install.

Comment: Not particularly, but I guess I figured the instructions provided by RabbitMQ's site should work pretty smoothly and must be missing something.

Comment: That's a common mistake made by other-OS power-users when they try to apply their skills to Linux. Upstream software works great IF you have the skills to make it work great. It's not automatic. That's why there are Linux distros -- to make software easier. And that's why the slightly-older version in the Ubuntu repositories is easier to install than the latest from upstream.

Comment: That's a bit of a leaping assumption, but OK.    The problem really is that the RabbitMQ site itself suggests that it's better to follow their guide, which doesn't provide any troubleshooting, and doesn't always seem to work if you follow it as written.  

That being said, do you have any suggestions for THAT, instead of handwaving the problem away via implying I don't know what I'm doing?

I came here to ask for help, not to receive implications that I don't have the proper skills to follow a guide.

Comment: Your apt error output tells you which keys were the mistake you (or perhaps the guide) made.